# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash in collectionView delegate `sizeForItemAt IndexPath` in UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, crashlytics

I am getting one crash in Crashlytics and the type of crash is `EXC_BREAKPOINT`. It is crashing at `sizeForItemAt indexpath` method of collection view. I am unable to repro the crash and it is happening majorly on iPads. It seems the crash due to some layout issue when orientation changes. Below is the stack trace from firebase: -

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

```
0  Module1                          0x10587bb78 specialized TabViewController.collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) + 227 (TabViewController.swift:227)

1  Module1                          0x1058799a8 @objc TabViewController.collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) + 4892 (<compiler-generated>:4892)

2  UIKitCore                      0x1a7c288f0 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfosWithExistingSizingDictionary:] + 2548

3  UIKitCore                      0x1a7c29eb4 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 280

4  UIKitCore                      0x1a7c23d30 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 224

5  UIKitCore                      0x1a7c1d594 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 276

6  UIKitCore                      0x1a7c1ddb4 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 108

7  UIKitCore                      0x1a7be76e8 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 228

8  UIKitCore                      0x1a8a1aa0c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2576

9  QuartzCore                     0x1a8ea1670 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 308

10 QuartzCore                     0x1a8ea1b54 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 548

11 QuartzCore                     0x1a8eb678c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 144

12 QuartzCore                     0x1a8df85e4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 500

13 QuartzCore                     0x1a8e247f4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684

14 UIKitCore                      0x1a84e9554 __83-[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]_block_invoke_4 + 48

15 UIKitCore                      0x1a84e890c -[UIApplication _performWithUICACommitStateSnapshotting:] + 148

16 UIKitCore                      0x1a84e9488 __83-[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]_block_invoke_2 + 604

17 UIKitCore                      0x1a8a0d920 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104

18 UIKitCore                      0x1a84e91f8 __83-[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]_block_invoke + 228

19 UIKitCore                      0x1a79603ec -[UIScene _applyOverrideSettings:forActions:] + 124

20 UIKitCore                      0x1a875c814 -[UIWindowScene _applySnapshotSettings:forActions:] + 48
```

Can someone suggest what could be the reason for the crash? Should we check if the `dataSource` count should be greater than `indexpath.item` in delegate methods?

Comment: Perhaps, when the orientation changes, more items are loaded into the active portion of the CollectionView. When you tried to reproduce the error did you scroll to the bottom of the CollectionView then change the orientation? Are you sure their's an associated model for each cell in the CollectionView? In my experience, these errors mostly arise from cells being created for indices that are out of range.

Comment: @jacob_g the issue is not reproducible when i scroll to bottom and then change the orientation. Yes, there is a model associated for each cell in collection-view. Not able to identify the crash scenario but from logs it seems it is mostly in landscape orientation. I have one question here, should we add the check for collection view `dataSource array count > indexPath.item` even if we are sure the condition will be true.

Comment: I would add logging to the function, outputting everything you can to understand what's causing the problem, including information about the dataSource and indexPath